# How can I hide the description of form`s filed. Django

Tags: python, django, forms

Good morning!

I have such problem: I want to hide the django`s description of form`s field. For example,

> Required. 30 characters or fewer. Usernames may contain alphanumeric,
>   _, @, +, . and - characters.

it is the description of username field. I want to hide it. My form:

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
        widgets = {
                    'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                        'class': 'form-control'
                    }),
                    'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                        'class': 'form-control'
                    }),
                    'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                        'class': 'form-control'
                    }),
                }
        labels = {
            'username': _(u"Логін"),
            'password': _(u'Пароль'),
            'email': _(u'Пошта')
            }
```

What must i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `help_text` of the concerned field to `None`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].help_text = None
```